# TL081 unused pins

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am using a TL081 op amp and I do not need to adjust the offset. What should I do with the unused pins (the offset adjustment ones and the disconnected one)? Just leave them floating?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the 8.2 functional block diagram you'll notice that they have a connection to the current mirror in the op amp which gives you the offset. It won't matter if you leave them floating. It may matter if you have a lot of RF radiating around in your application, but shouldn't matter in most.

Comment: In the latter case, what should I do? And what about the disconnected pin?

Comment: I would probably capacatively couple it to ground, actually, nevermind. The bandwidth for this part is 3Mhz, you'll probably never see HF noise on the output (I'm not going to say never, but it is highly unlikely). There are only two ways noise could get in through the pin, from strong RF and a high static electric field. I don't think there are many applications where there would be a problem, I would leave them floating, if your really worried about it put a guard\ground trace on the PCB around the pins.